# "Facebook Data Query Failed" error when logging in

Tags: support, status-completed, login, openid

I tried to login to Stack Overflow in Firefox via Facebook. After logging into Facebook, I was redirected back to SO with the following error.

[image: Facebook Data Query Failed]

What does this error mean and what may have caused it to happen?

Comment: I'm seeing this on Windows 8.1 with Internet Explorer 11 (11.0.9600.18618), but am able to log in without issue on Google Chrome.

Comment: Does this happen every time you try to log in or just intermittently? Sounds like a temporary connectivity issue between us and Facebook.

Comment: I am having the same problem, happens all the time. IE doesn't work just as firefox.

Comment: @Adam I bet it's something to do with the HTTPS changes on SE side, can you ping Nick and try to follow this lead?

Comment: I am not able to login either. Luckily I had my account logged in on another PC.

Comment: You should always keep backup login options for your account.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nah, login has already been running on HTTPS for ages. ;) Apparently Facebook [changed their API](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43063384).

Comment: Guess I'll be fixing our Facebook auth path this afternoon. Fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We relied on the version of the Facebook API that expired on March 25. The next oldest version changed the response format of the `oauth/access_token` route from a URL-encoded query string to JSON.

I updated our parsing of the response, and the fix is out in production now.

Answer (score 0):

While it is up to the development team to fix the issue, there is a way out until then. You can create a password for your account using your facebook email address without having to login.

---

### Step 1: Open login page and click on  "forget"

[image]

---

### Step 2: Enter your facebook email

[image]

---

### Step 3: You will receive an email which will allow you to set your password.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure this works only for those who have SE account **in addition** to Facebook login.

Comment: The email says "This email address is associated with an account, bu no password is associated with it yet, so it can't be used to log in". How can an account not have a password if it was created? Moreover, the email mentions that I am using my facebook account. It did not mention about my SE account.

Comment: One account can have several logins. Facebook is one of them. Google is another. Stack Exchange OpenID is yet another. What you mention in the answer is the last, Stack Exchange OpenID.

Comment: The email said "As a reminder, you can use any of the following credentials to log in to your account:" and the list had only one entry: my facebook account. Isn't that an indication that I have only one account? As far as I remember, I never created alternate accounts.

Comment: And were you really able to set a password for it? I suspect not.

Comment: Yes I did and I even logged in. I wasn't able to login until now on my daily use PC. I had to use an old ugly annoying computer which had my account already logged in. After setting my password, I was able to login using the email address and the newly created password.

Comment: hmm.... so I don't really understand what's going on. Hope this helps other people. :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is just creating an SE OpenID using your already associated FB email (you can't change your actual Facebook password through SE right?)... That of course *is* a workaround for not being able to log in, it's not a workaround for logging in *with* Facebook though.

Comment: Yes, it creates a SE OpenID as an alternate login method. It obviously won't change the facebook password. And yes, this answer does not really answer the question but those who are unable to login can use this workaround until the bug is fixed.